# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type -- error . how to solve this

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, datatables

Hi i have a code which gets the user details and , i have a view which reads the details from the controller. but i am getting this error.

My Controller looks like this

```
  var details =  
                (from u in db.Users
                 select new
                 {
                     u.UserID,
                     u.Name,
                     u.UserEmail,
                     u.UserAddress,
                     u.UserMobile,
                     u.UserCity,
                     u.RoleId
                 }).ToList();

            return View(details);



  @model IEnumerable<DueDimensions.Models.User>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UserDetailsDataView";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/AdminDashboardLayout.cshtml";
}

@section head{
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myDataTable').dataTable().makeEditable();
        });
    </script>
}

<div id="demo">
    <h1>Basic Example</h1>
    <table id="myDataTable" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>User Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Mobile Number</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Role</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr id="@item.UserID">
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.UserEmail</td>
                    <td>@item.UserAddress</td>
                    <td>@item.UserMobile</td>
                    <td>@item.UserCity</td>
                    <td>@item.Role</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="add_delete_toolbar" />
</div>
```

when i run the project , am getting an error as heading. what will be the reason, your dynamic help would help me lot. i am working with jquery datatables.

advance Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an `anonymous type` from controller, but expecting a strongly typed object `User` in View, Change your code like this:-

```
 (from u in db.Users
      select new User
      {
         UserID = u.UserID,
         Name = u.Name,
         UserEmail = u.UserEmail,
         Address = u.UserAddress,
         UserMobile = u.UserMobile,
         City = u.UserCity,
         RoleId = u.RoleId
      }).ToList();
```

Here I am considering, Your `User` type looks like this:-

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public string UserEmail {get; set; }
    public string Address {get; set; }
    public int UserMobile {get; set; }
    public string City{get; set; }
    public int RoleId {get; set; }
}
```

You need to change the properties accordingly.

Comment: But i get new error as
Error 17 Cannot initialize type 'DueDimensions.Models.User' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' D:\DueDimension Home\DueDimensions\DueDimensions\Controllers\AdminController.cs 193 33 DueDimensions

Comment: i am able to get out from that error, and caught in this ..
The entity or complex type 'DueDimensionsModel.User' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query. literally frustrating me..